# Stored Procedure in Access DB

Tags: database, ms-access, stored-procedures

I have an MS Access database (.mdb) with a front end of reports built onto it that generates a report to calculate the pay/profitability of an insurance agent. There is a column on the report (TASC bonus) that is not a column in the table. It is apparently calculated by a stored procedure (this is what I've been told). Is there a way to view the stored procedures in an Access database to detemine how this column is calculated? Unfortunately I cannot post the database due to security/privacy issues. I believe the data (and perhaps the stored procedure) in the Access database is extracted from a SQL database and then "massaged" for reports.

I am thinking there must be some sort of db viewer that would allow you to see all the tables and procedures but my Google searching has turned up nothing (and usually I'm pretty good at finding just about anything). I always post here as a last resort when I'm truly stumped!

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the database for the object (stored procedure) definition.  The particulars of the query required depends on the database you wish to connect to.

For MS SQL: select object_definition(object_id) from(sys.procedures) where name = '" & sProcName & "'"

For Oracle: select text from user_source where name = upper('" & sProcName & "') order by type, line

Hope that helps to get you there.

Comment: It's an Access Database (I don't have access to the original SQL database)

Comment: If you really have no access to the back end DBMS, you may be stuck. Try running the matching query from the answer above as a Pass-Through Query (may work, may not). Failing that, ask the DBA for either select-only rights on the DB or a copy of the SP's code.

Comment: Our issue is that the insurance agent who was generating these reports is no longer with the company. We are using the last database that he had in his document manager and would like to replicate his results. The company is very overprotective of it's database so they want us to re-make the front end and give it to them but they've only given us his database with old data in it to work with. (I know this is a pain to work with)

Answer (score 0):

Is the data stored in a Jet/ACE MDB/ACCDB or in SQL Server or some other database server? "Stored procedure" is not terminology that's native to Access and while there are certain things in common between some kinds of stored Access queries and what is meant by "stored procedure" in server databases, there's not a lot.

That said, you should look at the Recordsource of the report and post it as an edit to your answer. That will likely indicate where the data is coming from. It's highly unlikely, im my opinion, that the report is getting that data from a server-side stored procedure, but the SQL should provide clues as to where it's coming from.

Comment: As I mentioned in one of my comments on the first answer, it is an Access database that was extracted from a SQL database. It is my belief that the stored procedure (in the original SQL server) was extracted in some way as well because I can find it no where in the Access database, yet the field "TASC Bonus" is still somehow being calculated. I only have access to the Access database (which is old data) due to security/privacy policies. (It's like someone tying your hands and then telling you to paint a picture. It's a pain in the butt!)

Comment: You should still have access to the Recordsource of the report, no?

Comment: Sorry, I misread! I do have access to the Recordsource, that is correct. I will see if I can post it in my main post tomorrow afternoon when I have a chance!

Comment: Still waiting for the Recordsource -- not trying to be impatient! I'm just intrigued by whatever is causing the problem!

Comment: Sorry! We were sidetracked on a bunch of other issues (amazing how this hugely important report got pushed to the side by management in 2 seconds). I will post it up this evening!